# bufferoverflow chars gets replaced on stack

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, stack-overflow

So I try to understand stack based buffer-overflow but now I am stuck. This is the vulnerable function (32 bit ELF).

```
int test(char* input)
{
    char buf[100];
    printf("Buffer is at %p\n", &buf); // leak helper
    strcpy(buf, input);

    return 1;
}
```

I already calculated to number of bytes until the eip is overwritten (112 bytes). The exploit looks like this roughly like this `shellcode + '\x55' * (116 - len(shellcode) - 4) + '\x??\x??\x??\x??'`

The last 4 bytes are my return address and I get this value from the leak in the code (printf of buf address). The value of the address is something like 0x????ffff. Now when I fill the ?? with the little endian format the value from the leak \xff get's converted to `0xc3 0xbf` when I look into the stack memory. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please kindly share `checksec` output of the binary as well

Comment: I found the solution. My mistake was python3. I tried to generate the input in gdb with $(python3 -c ".....") but python3 handels stirngs and bytes differently than python2. So I switched to perl run $(perl -e 'print "..."') and now it works.

Comment: I think you need to format it as ASCII. It's definitely possible to achieve that with Python3

Comment: Since this was a syntax error, this is not a security question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using python3 because it online example python2 was used to create the input and python3 handels strings and bytes differently that python2.

To solve my issue I switched to perl `perl -e 'print "..."'`.